# Number of possible non crossing paths on a grid of $m$ by $n$ size?

Tags: combinatorics, soft-question

Given two points on 2 dimensional m by n grid, moving in units of 1 in either direction, how many non intersecting paths exist between the two points?

in other words, with taxi cab metric, on a m by n size grid , in how many possible non crossing ways can we get from a to b?

Can this be generalized for 3 dimensions or more? Is there a name for this type of problem in combinatorics?

Comment: Is this question inspired by your display picture? ;)

Comment: @suncup224 : Maybe, not sure why I really pondered about this, I should be applying for jobs rather than pondering math questions.